# Getting a div to fadeIn the opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a div to `fadeIn()` from white to the normal dark gray color. However, my attempt is failing and it is killing my other scripts on the page. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function(){
 $('.dark-gray').fadeTo(1200, 1);
}
```

```css
.dark-gray {
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #202020;
}
#dark-gray-container {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 150px 0;
}
#dark-gray-container-title {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#dark-gray-container-description {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 padding-top: 40px;
}
#dark-gray-container-button {
 padding-top: 80px;
}
#dark-gray-container-button-span {
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 20px 25px;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}
#dark-gray-container-button-span:hover {
 border: 2px solid #45a5ba;
 transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dark-gray">
  <div id="dark-gray-container">
   <div id="dark-gray-container-title">GET IN TOUCH WITH US</div>
   <div id="dark-gray-container-description">Looking for advice or would you like to speak to a member of the OD team? Please hit the button below.</div>
   <div id="dark-gray-container-button"><span id="dark-gray-container-button-span">CONTACT US</span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

UPDATE:

I want the function to start when the div is scrolled to. What about this?

```
$(function() {


var oTop = $('.green').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop );
        if( pTop > oTop ){
            fadeinGray();
        }
    });
});
function fadeinGray(){
    $('.dark-gray').fadeTo(1200, 1);
}
```

Comment: Your jQuery code is like that? or it is actually a part of a bigger code? This code is not correct

Comment: I have more jQuery, but the other jQuery is not involved with this particular code. Whatever I am doing wrong here is killing the rest.

Comment: If you are trying to define a function, this is not correct. It should be `function funcName(parameters) {}`. If it is nested inside another event, then it is correct: $(".selector").click(function(){ ... }). Which one is it?

Comment: It is not nested inside of another event. I did this: `function fadeinGray(){
 $('.dark-gray').fadeTo(1200, 1);
}` and it still isn't working...however, the other jQuery is now working.

Comment: how do you call your function? is it triggered by a click on an element or something? because you need to call this function somewhere based on an action to trigger it.

Comment: @zeropoint Look at my update in my question. What about something like that?

Comment: It still doesn't work with that, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out a working example [HERE](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/JGMJNB)

There were couple of issues. First your `dark-gray` class was always dark gray. You had to change the CSS opacity to something lower than 1 for the beginning. Then you were making it complicated to calculate the top offset.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I didn't know the opacity had to be set low at first. I thought it was a default if it wasn't specified.

Comment: @Becky: glad to help

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can use `fadeIn` when `mouseenter` this is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
       div.mystyle{
        width:500px;
        height: 500px;
        border:2px solid black;
       }

       div.check{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: gray;
        display: none;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="mystyle">
    <div class="check">

    </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".mystyle").mouseenter(function(){
            $(".check").fadeIn(1000);
        });

    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

if you want call back function(when mouse leave) use this code also.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".mystyle").mouseleave(function(){
                $(".check").fadeIn(1000);
            });

        });
```